# Why is FrozenList different from tuple?

Tags: python, pandas

```
from pandas.core.base import FrozenList

Type:        type
String form: <class 'pandas.core.base.FrozenList'>
File:        /site-packages/pandas/core/base.py
Docstring:
Container that doesn't allow setting item *but*
because it's technically non-hashable, will be used
for lookups, appropriately, etc.
```

Why not just use **tuple**? What extra functionality would a FrozenList offer?

Comment: From [here](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40p%40a%40pandas-HEAD%40pandas%40core%40index.py/14/pandas.core.base.FrozenList/python) it looks to support various protocols: radd (like list), mul/imul (with another FrozenList), etc. It also extends PandasObject.

Comment: Also, just because two types support the same functionality doesn't mean they're necessarily the same. There are regular proposals to add a `frozenlist` type to Python's builtins, because `tuple` is overloaded for two different purposes: heterogeneous fixed-length sequences (actual tuples) and immutable (often-homogeneous, arbitary-length) sequences. Guido has always shot the idea down because nobody could come up with a case where the confusion actually caused confusion… but he suggested that the current static-type-checking pre-PEP could conceivably be that case.

Comment: @abarnert: thanks for the info on the `frozenlist` proposal.  FWIW, I consider `tuple`s as Python's `frozenlist`, and `collections.namedtuple`s as Python's (real) tuples.  IOW, Python's builtin `tuple` is simply a poorly-named type, IMO.  It should have been called `frozenlist` from the get-go, alongside the `set`/`frozenset` pair.

Comment: @kjo: That pair didn't exist until much later. A single mutable `sets.Set` type was originally proposed for Python 2.2. It was only after people realized that you can't store a mutable set in a set that `sets.ImmutableSet` was added, but it was considered an internal detail: an automatic conversion in the `add` method, constructor, etc. would turn any `Set` argument into an `ImmutableSet`. It was only in 2.4 that `frozenset` was added. So, Guido's time machine would have had to be pretty impressive to base `tuple` naming in 0.x after experience from 2.3.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is an internal pandas construct. Not using tuple because:

- It inherits from a common pandas class
- Its customizable (e.g. the repr)
- It doesn't have quite all of the functions of a tuple (some are disabled)
- It nots hashable (so more like a list here and not a tuple)

The construct is used to represent a MultiIndex levels,labels, and names. The point of it is to prevent modification of these thru attributes and force the use of methods (e.g. `set_levels()`). As the state of these cannot be changed independent (for level/labels), but must be changed together.

These are 'public' properties though, so it needed an access mechanism that could do all of this (and yet still be changed internally if necessary, for performance reasons).

Comment: I know it says it's not hashable, but: `hash(pd.core.base.FrozenList((1,2,3)))` gives me `2528502973977326415` (and repeating with a distinct but equal `FrozenList` gives me the same hash).

Comment: So it is changeable, just not by the user.

Comment: yeh, don't recall the exact reason for the hashability. not really sure its even necessary.

Comment: Yep, the point was to allow it to internally be modifyiable, but not by the user (something like a ``.readonly`` flag kind of creation).

Comment: @Jeff: Actually, reading more carefully, it says it's "technically" not hashable. I'm not sure what that means; maybe it implies that it may or may not be hashable, but that's just an implementation detail that you shouldn't rely on?

Comment: @abarnert I don't remember. jtratner did this, don't recall the reasoning. (except maybe it was that technially a np.ndarray was not hashable so this shouldn't be either; kind of moot now that Index is not a ndarray subclass anymore though).