# What's the point of an immutable-but-non-hashable container class?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas defines a `FrozenList` object, described in its documentation as a

> [c]ontainer that doesn't allow setting item *but* because it's technically non-hashable, will be used for lookups, appropriately, etc.

**I don't understand what benefit there is in having an immutable-but-non-hashable container.**  Could someone give me an example where the hashability of a standard Python tuple would cause problems?

The answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25676107/559827) **does not give any reason** for why one would want an **immutable-but-non-hashable** container.  In particular, it does not explain why a Python tuple's **hashability** makes it unsuitable for whatever task the `FrozenList`s are being used for.  Therefore,

### THIS QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE.

Comment: What specifically do you want to know that is not addressed in that other question?

Comment: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676107/why-is-frozenlist-different-from-tuple#comment40127151_25676191); the object is mutable, by *code internal to Pandas*.

Comment: Most of all, it is an internal implementation detail of Pandas, not something you should really worry about here.

Comment: @BrenBarn: I've edited my post to answer your question.  See in particular the sentence in bold right after the quoted documentation.  (The answer to that other question on `FrozenList` does not explain how the hashability of Python tuples makes the unsuitable.  What is so difficult to understand about this question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is indeed a bit confusing, because the discussion on that question indicates that it is mutable via pandas internals, but I don't see how that ability is actually used.  Being unhashable has no specific benefit.  The benefit is that the object is mutable (although, again, as that question states, it is mutable only via the C internals, not via Python code).  If an object is mutable, it cannot be hashable.  (Or rather, it can cannot have its hash value depend on its mutable state; for an object like a list/tuple that has no real state except its mutable contents, there's no sensible way to make it hashable if it's mutable.)

In addition, there is this comment in the source code:

```
# Sidenote: This has to be of type list, otherwise it messes up PyTables
#           typechecks
```

As the other question also says, there are other reasons to use a custom class instead of tuple.  For instance, FrozenList has a custom `__repr__`.

Basically, it does not appear that the class was written because someone thought "I need an immutable but nonhashable container".  Rather, it appears it was written because someone thought "I need a class that is mutable, but only secretly, and I need to be able to give it custom methods, and I need it to be a subclass of `list` to avoid breaking this other library."  Some of the comments on that other question/answer suggest that nonhashability per se may never have been a necessary criterion, and even if was, it may no longer be necessary due to other changes in how pandas works.  I didn't write the class, so I can't be sure, but it seems to me that the comment you quoted in your question is misleading about what the real impetus was for making such a class.