# Unexpected Behavior for pd.DataFrame.drop when using with Multilevel Index dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've been getting an unexpected behavior after dropping a column from a multi-index dataframe in pandas.

I need to get the outermost (level=0) columns for a multi-index dataframe after dropping a column. To get the level=0 columns, I used:

```
df.columns.levels[0]
```

However, even after dropping a specific column from the original dataframe and assigning it to a new dataframe, I still get the same elements on the index list, instead of the updated column list.

For example:

```
INPUT: df
Box       '1'                  '2'                   '3'
Latency   code latency  loc    code latency  loc    code latency  loc
0         9170.  948.    L.    8170.  328.    R.    9160.  238.    L.
1         7540   1501.   R     9170.  9028.   L.    7170.   94.    L.
```

```
INPUT:df.columns.levels[0]
Out: Index(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='object', name='Box Number')



dropped_df = df.drop('2', axis=1, level=0)
INPUT: dropped_df.columns.levels[0]
Out: Index(['1', '2', '3'], dtype='object', name='Box Number')


INPUT: dropped_df
Out: 
Box       '1'                  '3'                  
Latency   code latency  loc    code latency  loc
0         9170.  948.    L.    9160.  238.    L.
1         7540   1501.   R     7170.   94.    L.
```

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong... 
Why is the updated dataframe (`dropped_df`) returning the same columns as the original dataframe even when the output of the updated df shows that the dataframe has been changed? Is the original dataframe being cached (copied) somewhere?

Any help / pointers would be appreciated!

NOTE: I'm using  python =3.6.8. / pandas =0.25.0

EDIT 1: The columns are `string` type, so it is not a matter of incorrect types affecting behavior.

Comment: can you try `dropped_df =df.drop(2, axis=1, level=0)` , may be the columns are int and not string?

Comment: The columns are strings because that's how I formatted the original dataframe. Also, if the column was an int, the columns wouldn't have been dropped after .drop() and the `dropped_df` would be identical to `df`. But I'll edit my original post to clarify the data type

Comment: Yeah, I just did, I get the same output as him. Dataframe updates, but printing `.columns.levels[0]` does not. I tried also passing `inplace=True` in the `.drop()` but "bug" keeps happening

Comment: I think I'm getting somewhere... Will post in a few.

Comment: yep thanks @CeliusStingher!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation and using the code you give as sample, and trying:

```
dropped_df.columns.levels[1] = dropped_df.columns.levels[1]
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError: 'FrozenList' does not support mutable operations.
```

Researching pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/internals.html) it seems that indeed as stated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676107/why-is-frozenlist-different-from-tuple):

> The construct is used to represent a MultiIndex levels,labels, and names. The point of it is to prevent modification of these thru attributes and force the use of methods (e.g. set_levels()). As the state of these cannot be changed independent (for level/labels), but must be changed together.

Explaining why when we see `dropped_df.columns.levels[1]` we get the Frozen (original) values, not equaling what we see when simply displaying `dropped_df`

Comment: I see - thanks for the answer! That makes total sense. Maybe I should create an issue requesting `Index` to be replaced with `FrozenList` at the output level so that people like me can debug faster. Outputting `Index` is definitely a bit misleading.

Comment: But I guess which leads me to another question, how can I mutate the elements in the FrozenList? Is there a way to make a FrozenList to some other mutable datatype? Or do I have to stick with using set_levels()?

Comment: It seems to me that it requires an extra import, the `frozenlist` project seems to address this issue, have a look at it: https://pypi.org/project/frozenlist/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @Celius. I'll definitely take a look at the project